# Command to show .php files ordererd by date last change or creation

Tags: debian

I need to show all .php files created or modified within 1 day (or last tot entries)

Is there a command for this?

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
find / -name "*.php" -mtime -1
```

You can restrict it to a subdirectory by changing `/` to something like `/var/www/`.

Comment: -mtime -1 means -1 days?

Comment: It means less than 1 day ...

Comment: You can also put `+1` in there which means "more than one day ago" rather than "modified one day in the future".